# Is there any software to disconnect the lan or wi-fi network connection when you stop using a specific application?

Tags: windows, open-source, software-development, networking, security

I am looking for some software that has the functionality of disconnecting the lan or wi-fi network when closing a specific application and that when opening the application, reconnect.

This could help protect the computer from future network attacks when it is not in use.

My operating system is Windows 7